# Skipping incorrect syntax errors in SQL with unknown data set using WHERE ... IN (' ')

Tags: python, sql, pandas

So I'm reading a list of part numbers from excel using Pandas, which can be just about anything, like:

287380274-87
or
ME982394-01
or
HOU8929

that changes randomly based on what the user is looking for and can contain some bad numbers as well. Such as blanks, invalid characters (<, >, or !), as well as phrases, like '12390-01 to 04'. I don't care about filtering the part numbers for all of the random conditions that throw synxtax errors in SQL. But I am attempting to query a SAP database WHERE part number IN (list):

```
import pandas as pd
from hdbcli import dbapi

userFile = r'T:\H01 Cell\Projects\Part Breakdown Update Spreadsheet Improvements\2022.03.21 Part Breakdown update - VK.xlsm'

# read input from excel for part numbers to WHERE in queries
partNums = pd.read_excel\
    (io=userFile, sheet_name='Inputs', usecols=lambda x: 'Unnamed' not in x,\
        skiprows=1, dtype={'Part List' : str})

# Open SAP database connection
conn = dbapi.connect(address="server", port=####, user="XXXXX", password="XXXXXXX")

# Function to convert  
def listToString(s): 
    # use list comprehension
    listToStr = ', '.join([str(elem) for elem in s])
    # return string  
    return listToStr

partNumStr = listToString(partNums['Part List'].drop_duplicates().tolist())

# GetInvOnHand()
# DISTINCT List
queryIOHlist = [
    "PART_NO",
    "PLANT",
    "LOCATION_DESCRIPTION",
    "VALUATION_TYPE"
]
queryIOHstr = listToString(queryIOHlist)
# our SQL query, select all from ' '
queryInvOnHand = (
                    "SELECT DISTINCT " +
                    queryIOHstr +
                    " FROM ZWILLIAMS.ZV_WI_GU_INVENTORY_ON_HAND_IM_THIN INV" +
                    " WHERE PART_NO IN " +
                    "(" +
                    partNumStr +
                    ")"
                )
# pandas read SQL to store SQL table in dataframe
inventoryOnHand = pd.read_sql(queryInvOnHand, conn)

conn.close()
```

I'm running into synxtax errors for my SQL query because of these bad part numbers, such as:

```
(257, 'sql syntax error: incorrect syntax near "to": line 1 col 8120 (at pos 8120))
```

where the part number it doesn't like is: 62219-01 to -04

In SQL, is there a way to just skip that number if not found in the Part Numbers column in the table? Ideally, it would just be something like:

```
if syntaxError:
    continue
```

and then just not record anything in my dataframe for that part number.

Comment: Use a prepared statement with parameters rather than concatenating strings into the SQL.

Comment: The problem you're having is that you didn't put quotes around the part number strings.

Comment: @Barmar thank you, I was confused as to why it wasn't working as I thought it would. I just added another function to create my part num string that uses: <code> listToStr = ', '.join(["'" + str(elem) + "'" for elem in s]) </code> to put quotes around my part number strings and it worked.

Comment: Don't do that. Use a prepared statement with parameters.

Comment: @Barmar, oh ok, I see what you mean now. I've scarcely ever used SQL, I'll look into how to write a prepared statement with parameters. Before you said it, I didn't know that was a thing. Thank you again